# dim error with pytorch Dataloader, bertModel

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model

I'm using distilBert in an nn.Module class and pytorch Dataset from P3 for dataloaders.

The input into Bert model: outputs = self.bert(**input), is a dictionary of input ids etc. and the input_ids has size (batch_size, sequence_length).

In my **get_items**() in the custom Dataset class, I return one such dictionary at once and the dimension of input_ids is correct.

```
    return self.X[index], self.start[index], self.end[index]
    
    >>> self.X[index] 
    >>>{'input_ids': tensor([[  101,  2054,  2001,  2171,  1997, 20773,  2015,  2034,  3948,  2201,
               102, 20773, 21025, 19358, 22815, 10010,  3334, 12170, 23432, 29715,
              3501, 29678, 12325, 29685, 10506, 14001, 24322,  2141,  2244,  1018,
              3261,  2003,  2137,  3220,  6009,  2501,  3135,  1998,  3883,  2141,
              1998,  2992,  1999,  5395, .......
```

Then in training I did (model is Bert that i defined with pretrained BertModel):

```
   for (input, expected_start, expected_end) in train_loader:
   
    optimizer.zero_grad()
   
    print(input)
   
    start, end = model(input) // ERROR: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

```
class Bert(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, h, output_dim):
    super(Bert, self).__init__()
    self.bert = DistilBertModel.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased')
    self.start_linear = nn.Linear(h, output_dim)
    self.end_linear = nn.Linear(h, output_dim)
    self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
    self.loss = nn.NLLLoss()
  
  def forward(self, input):
    # print(input.size())
    outputs = self.bert(**input) # input = bert tokenizer encoding
    lhs = outputs.last_hidden_state # (batch_size, sequence_length, hidden_size)
    out = outputs[:, -1, :] # (batch_size, hidden_dim)
    st = self.start_linear(lhs)
    end = self.end_linear(lhs) # or (st)?

    predict_start = self.softmax(st)
    predict_end = self.softmax(end)

    return predict_start, predict_end
......
```

```
def get_data_loaders(train, val, batch_size = 32):
  dataset = QAData(train + val) # preprocessed

  train_idx = [i for i in range(len(train))]
  val_idx = [i for i in range(len(train), len(train)+len(val))]

  train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_idx)
  train_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=train_sampler)

  val_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(val_idx)
  val_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, sampler=val_sampler)

  return train_loader, val_loader
```

But the input_ids in "input" in `start, end = model(input)` here becomes 3D:

```
    {'input_ids': tensor([[[  101,  2054,  2001,  2171,  1997, 20773,  2015,  2034,  3948,  2201,
               102, 20773, 21025, 19358, 22815, 10010,  3334, 12170, 23432, 29715,
              3501, 29678, 12325, 29685, 10506, 14001, 24322,  2141,  2244,  1018,
              3261,  2003,  2137,  3220,  6009,  2501,  3135,  1998,  3883,  2141,
              1998,  2992,  1999,  5395, .....
```

I'm wondering if there's any way to solve this? Or am I doing the batching wrong? Is it the right way to feed batches into my model? Thank you!!!

EDIT: error trace

```
in train_and_eval(number_of_epochs, model, train_loader, val_loader, save_file_name)
      1 def train_and_eval(number_of_epochs, model, train_loader, val_loader, save_file_name = None):
      2   optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(), lr=1e-5)
----> 3   train_epoch(model, train_loader, optimizer)
      4   return

<ipython-input-31-97b02296ac3b> in train_epoch(model, train_loader, optimizer)
     44     optimizer.zero_grad()
     45     print("****",input)
---> 46     start, end = model(input)
     47 
     48     # total += start.size()[0]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

<ipython-input-31-97b02296ac3b> in forward(self, input)
     15   def forward(self, input):
     16     # print(input.size())
---> 17     outputs = self.bert(**input) # input = bert tokenizer encoding
     18     lhs = outputs.last_hidden_state # (batch_size, sequence_length, hidden_size)
     19     out = outputs[:, -1, :] # (batch_size, hidden_dim)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/models/distilbert/modeling_distilbert.py in forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, head_mask, inputs_embeds, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    485             output_attentions=output_attentions,
    486             output_hidden_states=output_hidden_states,
--> 487             return_dict=return_dict,
    488         )
    489 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/models/distilbert/modeling_distilbert.py in forward(self, x, attn_mask, head_mask, output_attentions, output_hidden_states, return_dict)
    307 
    308             layer_outputs = layer_module(
--> 309                 x=hidden_state, attn_mask=attn_mask, head_mask=head_mask[i], output_attentions=output_attentions
    310             )
    311             hidden_state = layer_outputs[-1]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/models/distilbert/modeling_distilbert.py in forward(self, x, attn_mask, head_mask, output_attentions)
    254             mask=attn_mask,
    255             head_mask=head_mask,
--> 256             output_attentions=output_attentions,
    257         )
    258         if output_attentions:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
    725             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    726         else:
--> 727             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    728         for hook in itertools.chain(
    729                 _global_forward_hooks.values(),

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/transformers/models/distilbert/modeling_distilbert.py in forward(self, query, key, value, mask, head_mask, output_attentions)
    158             seq_length, dim) Contextualized layer. Optional: only if `output_attentions=True`
    159         """
--> 160         bs, q_length, dim = query.size()
    161         k_length = key.size(1)
    162         # assert dim == self.dim, 'Dimensions do not match: %s input vs %s configured' % (dim, self.dim)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Comment: What is the error that you get? can you please post the stack-trace?

Comment: edited! could you plz take a look? ty!